# customize url using Rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Basic question I am struggling to find an solution for.

I have an url `www.example.com/signup/form.html` i would like to rewrite the url as `www.example.com/signup` removing the form.html from the url but stil direct to this html file.

I have tried some sulotion to this, i do have a `.htaccess` file in my root with `RewriteEngine on`.

for some reason for a second it loads as `www.example.com/signup` and the suddenly redirects to 404 - page not found.

**This is what i currently use (not working):**

`RewriteRule ^signup/form.html.*$ http://www.example.com/signup/ [R=301,L]`

Also tried this :

`RewriteRule ^signup/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/signup [R=301,L]`

Also i have this on the top of my .htaccess file, might this be the reason i get the 404 ?

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
<Files ~ "^.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files> 
<Files ~ "includes$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files ~ "mods$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_flag error_reporting off
Options -Indexes
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
FileETag none
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Jan 2035 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]



Redirect 301 /default.aspx http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /home.asp http://www.example.com

Redirect 301 /contact.aspx http://www.example.com/contact/enquire
Redirect 301 /awards.aspx http://www.example.com/awards
Redirect 301 /event.asp http://www.example.com/visitus/events

Redirect 301 /social.aspx http://www.example.com/visitus/events
Redirect 301 /recipes.aspx‎ http://www.example.com/news/09/recipes
Redirect 301 recipes.aspx‎ http://www.example.com/news/09/recipes
Redirect 301 /recipes.asp http://www.example.com/news/09/recipes
Redirect 301 recipes.asp http://www.example.com/news/09/recipes
Redirect 301 /styles http://www.example.com/


Redirect 301 /home.asp?pid=24&page=4 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /home.asp?pid=13&page=2 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /home.asp?pid=42&page=3 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /home.asp?pid=12&page=1 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /home.asp?pid=71&page=3 http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /event.asp?pid=30&page=2 http://www.example.com/visitus/events
Redirect 301 /event.asp?pid=63 http://www.example.com/visitus/events


RewriteRule ^pg([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=page&id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-pg([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=$1&pg=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=$1&id=$2




RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/0([1-9]|[1-9]([0-9]+))/pg([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-\/]+)$ index.php?content=$1&cat=$2&pg=$4

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/0([1-9]|[1-9]([0-9]+))/([a-z0-9\-\/]+)$ index.php?content=$1&cat=$2
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-day-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$ index.php?content=$1&view=day&y=$2&m=$3&d=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-month-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})$ index.php?content=$1&view=month&y=$2&m=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-year-([0-9]{4})$ index.php?content=$1&view=year&y=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)-archs([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=$1&view=archives&pg=$2

RewriteRule ^images/lightbox-btn-next.gif images/lightbox-btn-next.png
RewriteRule ^images/lightbox-btn-prev.gif images/lightbox-btn-prev.png
RewriteRule ^images/lightbox-btn-close.gif images/lightbox-btn-close.png

DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex form.html
```

I did research [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules) on this , but i dont know im struggling to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue in a way a not really wanted to but anyways,my **solution** is.. added my .html file to the root(not in any directory) and renamed the file to signup.html and the used .htaccess Rewrite to remove the .html

> .htaccess (Rewrite)

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
 RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Also added an redirect for any person that already have the previous address:

> .htaccess (Redirect)

```
Redirect 301 /signup/index.html http://www.exapmle.com/signup
```

Did not really want to move my .html file from sub directory but this was my only solution that 'worked'.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Was an odd one.

Comment: yess it was, thanks allot man your help was much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite rule checks for any request that ends with `/index.html`, and removes the `index.html` bit if any are found.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

EDIT:

Try this also, this should cover both `.html` and `.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thnaks! this must be the solution...but this does the same as i mentioned in my question it loads as `www.example.com/signup/` but then redirects to 404, ill check in my .htaccess file, might be something else that is causing this.

Comment: Where are you placing it in the file? My assumption is that it is conflicting with other rules. Try placing it at the top.

Comment: its so weird, I place it on top of everything , then as it loads url im expecting (/signup/) , it redirects to 404.... im trying to figure out what could be doing this..

Comment: I've made an edit for you to attempt if the first one still isn't working.

Comment: amended my question to what i think might be causing this 404 problem.. ill try your edit now, thanks much appreciated

Comment: nothing works man, it loads the page and url as i want it but before the content shows on the page the url redirects to 404, i did EDIT my question above, you think that might have an influence on this RewriteRule ?

Comment: The `DirectoryIndex` part could. At this stage all I can advise that you do is comment sections out and keep testing until you find the part that is conflicting with the new rules. A painful task, but sometimes a necessary one.

Answer (score 0):

The correct .htaccess syntax to obtain it is:

```
RewriteRule ^/signup(.*)$ /signup/index.html [R=301,L]
```

It means that both /signup and /signup/ will be redirected to /signup/index.html

Comment: Thanks, it works meaning im not redirecting to an 404 but the url stays the same `www.example.com/signup/index.html` and it should look like this `www.example.com/signup`